# Convert uint64_t to std::string

Tags: c++, string, std, uint64

How can I transfer uint64_t value to std::string?
I need to construct the std::string containing this value
For example something like this:

```
void genString(uint64_t val)
{
      std::string str;
      //.....some code for str 
      str+=(unsigned int)val;//????
}
```

Thank you

Comment: On Windows (MSVC) you can use the `%I64d` format specifier when using `std::sprintf`

Comment: @Jonas - given this is clearly C++ I'd strongly advise keeping well clear of `sprintf`, especially with non-portable extensions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use either `boost::lexical_cast` or `std::ostringstream`

e.g.:

```
str += boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(val);
```

or

```
std::ostringstream o;
o << val;
str += o.str();
```

Comment: Can you give me the code example how to use std::ostringstream?

Comment: @yakov - added examples for both. You'll need either `#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>` or `#include <sstream>` depending on which solution you use.

Comment: Downvoted since by now, the standard C++11 solution should be used - std::to_string.

Answer (score 36):

In C++ 11 you may just use:

```
std::to_string()
```

it's defined in header

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/

Answer (score 5):

I use something like this code below. Because it's a template it will work with any type the supports operator<< to a stream.

```
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
std::string tostring(const T& t)
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << t;
    return ss.str();
}
```

for example

```
uint64_t data = 123;
std::string mystring = tostring(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string genString(uint64_t val)
{
   char temp[21];
   sprintf(temp, "%z", val);
   return temp;
}
```

Comment: To whomever may use this in the future, make sure to make your buffer big enough. Also you could make that buffer `static` if you wanted to add a little more efficiency.

Comment: @Seth - is static (and hence not reentrant) really faster than changing the stack pointer increase at entering the function from `n` to `n + 21`?

Comment: @Seth - gcc 4.4 with -O3 on ia32 gives me the exact opposite behaviour. `static` makes it consistently (slightly) slower (more than the error) on 100 repetitions of a 10,000,000 call loop. Seems like premature optimisation to me. The main chance in the local version is `subl $72, %esp` vs `subl $52, %esp`, an O(1) change.

Comment: @nmi - I don't think `%z` is correct - I get `test.cc:10:29: warning: conversion lacks type at end of format` and 
`test.cc:10:29: warning: too many arguments for format` with gcc