# std::lexical_cast - is there such a thing?

Tags: c++, parsing, casting, std

Does the C++ Standard Library define this function, or do I have to resort to Boost?

I searched the web and couldn't find anything except Boost, but I thought I'd better ask here.

Comment: You can "resort" to stringstreams too :)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Only partially.

C++11 `<string>` has `std::to_string` for the built-in types:

> `[n3290: 21.5/7]:`
>
> ```
> string to_string(int val);
> string to_string(unsigned val);
> string to_string(long val);
> string to_string(unsigned long val);
> string to_string(long long val);
> string to_string(unsigned long long val);
> string to_string(float val);
> string to_string(double val);
> string to_string(long double val);
> ```
>
> *Returns:* Each function returns a `string` object holding the
>   character representation of the value of its argument that would
>   be generated by calling `sprintf(buf, fmt, val)` with a format
>   specifier of `"%d"`, `"%u"`, `"%ld"`, `"%lu"`, `"%lld"`, `"%llu"`,
>   `"%f"`, `"%f"`, or `"%Lf"`, respectively, where `buf` designates
>   an internal character buffer of sufficient size.

There are also the following that go the other way around:

> `[n3290: 21.5/1, 21.5/4]:`
>
> ```
> int stoi(const string& str, size_t *idx = 0, int base = 10);
> long stol(const string& str, size_t *idx = 0, int base = 10);
> unsigned long stoul(const string& str, size_t *idx = 0, int base = 10);
> long long stoll(const string& str, size_t *idx = 0, int base = 10);
> unsigned long long stoull(const string& str, size_t *idx = 0, int base = 10);
> float stof(const string& str, size_t *idx = 0);
> double stod(const string& str, size_t *idx = 0);
> long double stold(const string& str, size_t *idx = 0);
> ```

However, there's nothing generic that you can use (at least [not until TR2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1973.html), maybe!), and nothing at all in C++03.

Comment: Hum, actually there is [`stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) and friends :)

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Oh, hey.. so there is! Thanks.

Comment: Stroustrup in his FAQ on c++11 uses it http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#constexpr in the section on delegating constructors

Comment: @mcheema: http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#delegating-ctor then. Either he means Boost, or he's using it as an arbitrary abstraction for the purpose of making a point, or he's wrong.

Comment: OK thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just assumed that the FAQ would be written in pure C++11 style given Stroustrup's interest in spreading good coding style practices.

Comment: @mcheema: We can all be interested in spreading good coding style practices, but that doesn't make them any less subjective!

Comment: @mcheema Remembering Stroustrup's addiction of using bold italic proportional font for code, I don't think one can ever seriously talk about the style of his code. _*joke*_

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I haven't seen any more rumblings about this making it into a Technical Specification. Did it die T.T

Comment: @JonathanMee: If anything I'd expect to see it in the Lib Fundamentals TS but there's no evidence of that. Looks to me like it died but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 20):

No it isn't, even in C++11, but it's [proposed for inclusion](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1973.html) in Technical Report 2, the next set of std library extensions.

Comment: What's the status of that for C++17, by the way?

Comment: According to Wikipedia there will be not TR2  because ISO procedures were changed, but Technical Specifications only (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1#Technical_Report_2).

Answer (score 11):

There's no std::lexical_cast, but you can always do something similar with [stringstreams](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/stringstream/):

```
template <typename T>
T lexical_cast(const std::string& str)
{
    T var;
    std::istringstream iss;
    iss.str(str);
    iss >> var;
    // deal with any error bits that may have been set on the stream
    return var;
}
```

Comment: thanks but that would be even slower than boost::lexical_cast

Comment: A stream based solution isn't going to be as fast as something like snprintf, but you didn't mention performance concerns in your question.

Comment: I'm kidding now, but when we talk about C++ solutions isn't performance concerns given ;)? Anyway boost also uses streams but they do also specialize them that's why it's very hard to beat them.

Comment: @smallB: note that `boost::lexical_cast` degenerates to this version when types are unknown. Also, you need not only deal with error bits, but also check that the buffer has been emptied.

Comment: Performance is always a concern, but it is never the only concern.  Simplicity, clarity, correctness, and maintainability are also very important.  I wouldn't use the above code in a tight loop, but it might be just fine for other situations.  A common question in regards to performance on SO is if you've profiled your code, and found that the sacrifice of other concerns are worthwhile :)

Comment: If you end up using `lexical_cast<string>(string)` this will only return the first word, not what you pass in. (You might use it in a templated function or something, not directly.) Something to look out for.

Comment: This version can be sped up a lot by making `iss` static

Comment: @MattMcNabb, maybe but then you've have to reset the ISS's buffer every time, and it wouldn't be thread safe.  It was a simple example.  Making it fool proof is an exercise for the reader/Boost library ;)

Comment: While the idea is correct, this answer has it backwards. The function declaration should be 'template <typename T> const std::string lexical_cast(const T& val) { ... }

Answer (score 6):

No it's a pure Boost thing only.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want boost then a lightweight library called [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) implements the following:

```
// Works with all the C++11 features and AFAIK faster then boost or standard c++11
std::string string_num = fmt::format_int(123456789).str(); // or .c_str()
```

More examples from the [official page](http://fmtlib.net/latest/syntax.html#format-examples).

Accessing arguments by position:

```
format("{0}, {1}, {2}", 'a', 'b', 'c');
// Result: "a, b, c"
format("{}, {}, {}", 'a', 'b', 'c');
// Result: "a, b, c"
format("{2}, {1}, {0}", 'a', 'b', 'c');
// Result: "c, b, a"
format("{0}{1}{0}", "abra", "cad");  // arguments' indices can be repeated
// Result: "abracadabra"
```

Aligning the text and specifying a width:

```
format("{:<30}", "left aligned");
// Result: "left aligned                  "
format("{:>30}", "right aligned");
// Result: "                 right aligned"
format("{:^30}", "centered");
// Result: "           centered           "
format("{:*^30}", "centered");  // use '*' as a fill char
// Result: "***********centered***********"
```

Replacing %+f, %-f, and % f and specifying a sign:

```
format("{:+f}; {:+f}", 3.14, -3.14);  // show it always
// Result: "+3.140000; -3.140000"
format("{: f}; {: f}", 3.14, -3.14);  // show a space for positive numbers
// Result: " 3.140000; -3.140000"
format("{:-f}; {:-f}", 3.14, -3.14);  // show only the minus -- same as '{:f}; {:f}'
// Result: "3.140000; -3.140000"
```

Replacing %x and %o and converting the value to different bases:

```
format("int: {0:d};  hex: {0:x};  oct: {0:o}; bin: {0:b}", 42);
// Result: "int: 42;  hex: 2a;  oct: 52; bin: 101010"
// with 0x or 0 or 0b as prefix:
format("int: {0:d};  hex: {0:#x};  oct: {0:#o};  bin: {0:#b}", 42);
// Result: "int: 42;  hex: 0x2a;  oct: 052;  bin: 0b101010"
```

Comment: I really like the ``fmt`` library and like to see its usage promoted. ``fmt``, however, will only do the *to string* conversion. (Now it does that better than any other C++ library I have seen.) ``fmt`` does not do the *from string*  conversion performed by lexical_cast or std::stoxyz functions.