# C++ Invalid conversion from

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve [this](http://www.codechef.com/ANDR2012/problems/A106) problem and i get such an error [ Invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char' ] ,but i can't figure out how to solve it. Here are the lines in which the problem is :

```
Declarations:
string alp("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
string formatted;
char partoftext[20];
size_t found;
```

---

```
found = text.copy(partoftext,2,0);
partoftext[found] = '\0';
a = atoi(partoftext);
formatted.append(alp[a]);

...
```

and the problem is in this line of code :

```
formatted.append(alp[a]);
```

thanks.

Comment: you do not give enough context. what is formatted? what is the error? what is a?

Comment: i've edited. sorry guys.

Comment: It would help if you indicated which line was giving the error.  It would help even more if you condensed the code down to a complete module, which we could copy/paste and compile (or try to compile) directly.

Comment: i've indicated the line which gives the error, and told what error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From :http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/

```
formatted.append(1, alp[a]);

/*
string& append ( const string& str );
string& append ( const string& str, size_t pos, size_t n );
string& append ( const char* s, size_t n );
string& append ( const char* s );
string& append ( size_t n, char c );
*/
```

Comment: one more question, why it's showing zeroes instead of letters? http://ideone.com/92d5F

Comment: It is not a 0 but 'O'. Also you could use supstr instead of copy and stringstream instead of atoi-> or take a look on boost::lexical_cast
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065413/stdlexical-cast-is-there-such-a-thing

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is correct (and it's a guess because you don't specify what the error actually is), try:

`formatted.append(alp, a, 1);`