# std::stringstream hex conversion error

Tags: c++, stl, hex, stringstream, data-conversion

I tried to do hex conversions using `std::stringstream` as the following:

```
std::stringstream s;
s << std::hex;

int i;

s << "100";
s >> i;     // 256

s << "10";  // doesn't work
s >> i;
```

But it fails on subsequent conversions as the comment points out. Do I need to reset the `stringstream`? Why does it fail?

Comment: How exactly does it "fail"?

Comment: @Singer: quite literally, the stream enters a `fail` state `;-)`.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13891856/187543 I haven't searched before posting the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing formatted input and after extracting i out of the string-stream the eofbit is set. Hence you have to clear the state or all following formatted input/output will fail.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream s;
    s << std::hex;

    int i;

    s << "100";
    s >> i;     // 256
    std::cout << i << '\n';
    s.clear();  // clear the eofbit
    s << "10";  
    s >> i;     // 16
    std::cout << i << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check stream state after `s << "10"`, you will see the operation failed. I don't know exactly why, but you can fix this problem by resetting the stream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  std::stringstream s;
  s << std::hex;

  int i;

  s << "100";
  s >> i;     // 256

  std::cout << i << '\n';

  s.str("");
  s.clear(); // might not be necessary if you check stream state above before and after extraction

  s << "10";  // doesn't work
  s >> i;

  std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6692d21e44f29f8a).

Comment: It seems like as if it is necessary to use `s.clear()` right after you extract something to be able to use the stringstream again.

Comment: Ah yes, sounds logical. I wasn't thinking straight :-)