# How to avoid repeated istringstream construction when converting stream of string tokens

Tags: c++, c++11, tostring, generic-programming, lexical-cast

I'm (intending to) use the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1122720/1593077) to read something from a CSV. Essentially I get an iterator to strings between consecutive `,` characters; but instead of putting them in a vector of strings, I want to parse these strings into elements of (arbitrary) type T, which comes from  template argument. So...

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const std::string& line) 
{
    // ....
    std::vector<T> vec;
    using namespace boost;
    tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char> > tk(
       line, escaped_list_separator<char>('\\', ',', '\"'));
    for (tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char> >::iterator i(tk.begin());
       i!=tk.end();++i) 
    {
       /* magic goes here */
    }
```

I could use an istringstream` (e.g. as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8065539/1593077)):

```
std::istringstream iss(*i);
T t; iss >> t;
vec.push_back(t);
```

But that's overkill (and I might be constructing twice or even three times here). If C++ had an `std::from_string()` like its `std::to_string`, then I would just do

```
vec.emplace_back(std::from_string(*i));
```

but that doesn't exist. Perhaps `boost::lexical_cast`? I'd really rather using something standard.

What should I do instead?

Comment: The only "generic" way to create something like a `from_string` function *is* with string streams, and it's actually how `boost::lexical_cast` works. It does of course rely on the type (`T` whatever that is) to have an appropriate ` operator>>` overload. You might have some specializations for thing like numbers, where e.g. `strtod` or `stoi` are used) but other than that there's no way to escape the clutches of the `istringstream`.

Comment: Even if a `from_string` function existed I don't see it doing much of an improvement performance/space wise. Merely a 2-3n extra operations, resulting in an overall O(n). Clean-code wise, you can just encapsulate your own template `from_string` through `sstream`s.

Comment: @aybassiouny: 1. You mean from_string. 2. An istringstream probably requires some construction 3. An istringstream does its own peeking, tokenization, maintaining the next unused position etc. while in my case I know there's just one value in the whole string. I'm sure there's some performance benefit in that.

Answer (score 0):

make the istringstream `static thread_local`

```
T parse (const string& line){
  static thread_local istringstream stream;
  stream.str(""); //flush the stream
  //keep using stream
}
```

if your application is mono-threaded, you can discard the `thread_local`

other solution which does not involve keeping the stream static to a function is to wrap the stream with `Parser` object, and keep using that object, flushing it's inner buffer with `str`

```
class Parser{
  std::stringstream stream;
  public:
  void parse(const std::string& data){
     stream.str("");
     // the rest
  }

}

Parser parser;
parser.parse("my,data");
parser.parse("other,data");
```

EDIT:
In order to prevent instansiation for every `T` type, encapsulate the stream in diferent function, 
make a helper function which constructs `std::istringstream` once form every thread:

```
namespace detail {
istringstream& getStream(){
      static thread_local istringstream stream;
      stream.str("");
      return stream;
}
} // namespace detail

template<class T>
void parse(){
   auto& stream = detail::getStream();
   //do soemthing with stream

}
```

Comment: Is that a Dangerous Dave image you have for an avatar?

Comment: yep. I'm Dave. and I'm dangerous :)

Comment: Wait, your templated parse function will give me a separate istream object for every value of T. That's not so good... how about an untemplated istringstream getter function, which keeps the static thread_local variable? Also, is thread_local C++11? C++14? C++17?

Comment: it will, but how many string types are you going to use? 2? 4? it's nothing building 4 stringstream objects. and thread_local + magic statics is C++14

Comment: I mean, let's take the worst case scenario when you have four types of strings (string,wstring,u16string,u32string) and you activate this function from 10 different threads. you will build only 40 objects which will take what? 20 nanoseconds? it's really nothing

Comment: Nobody said T is a string type, it's can be any type.

Comment: Also, it seems [thread_local is C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

Comment: @DavidHaim Shouldn't `getStream()` have also `stream.clear()`?

Comment: @DavidHaim Hmm, it doesn't look so: http://ideone.com/qYGrU7 Or I'm doing something wrong.