# So, we have int32_t, int16_t, uint64_t, etc.. But where are the atoi32, atoi16, atoui64, etc...?

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to convert a string input representing numbers to the respective numeric types. The problem is that I have strict type requirements, so, for instance, I cannot accept an **x >= 2^15** where an `int16_t` value (signed) is expected.

How can I deal with this scenario, without writing all the conversion functions from scratch?

P.S.

Please, do not suggest `boost::lexical_cast` - I am using it already. The functions I am talking about are going to replace the default implementation of the `lexical_cast` template by means of the particular template specializations, namely:

```
template<>
inline int32_t lexical_cast<int32_t,char const *>(const char * const & arg)
{
}
template<>
inline int16_t lexical_cast<int16_t,char const *>(const char * const & arg)
{
}
...
```

Ideally, it would be nice to have functions, like `atoi32`, `atoi16`, `atoiu64`, etc...

**EDIT**

I am using VS2010, so no luck with `<cinttypes>`.

Yes, it would be nice to have an improved `atoi` family of functions having the same error support as `strtol`.

**EDIT2**

Thought it was worthwhile to post my solution:

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <limits>

namespace boost {

template<class TInt, class conv>
TInt atoi(conv f, const char *arg)
{
  char* stop;
  TInt res = f(arg, &stop, 10);
  if (*stop)
  {
    throw_exception(bad_lexical_cast(typeid(TInt), typeid(const char *)));
  }
  return res;
}

template<class TInt>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<TInt>::value, TInt>::type atoi(const char *arg)
{
  char* stop;
  long res = strtol(arg, &stop, 10);
  if (*stop || std::numeric_limits<TInt>::min() > res || std::numeric_limits<TInt>::max() < res)
  {
    throw_exception(bad_lexical_cast(typeid(TInt), typeid(const char *)));
  }
  return (TInt)res;
}

template<class TInt>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<TInt>::value, TInt>::type atoi(const char *arg)
{
  char* stop;
  unsigned long res = strtoul(arg, &stop, 10);
  if (*stop || std::numeric_limits<TInt>::max() < res)
  {
    throw_exception(bad_lexical_cast(typeid(TInt), typeid(const char *)));
  }
  return (TInt)res;
}

template<> inline int8_t lexical_cast<int8_t,char const *>(const char * const & arg)
{
  return atoi<int8_t>(arg);
}

template<> inline uint8_t lexical_cast<uint8_t,char const *>(const char * const & arg)
{
  return atoi<uint8_t>(arg);
}

template<> inline int16_t lexical_cast<int16_t,char const *>(const char * const & arg)
{
  return atoi<int16_t>(arg);
}

template<> inline uint16_t lexical_cast<uint16_t,char const *>(const char * const & arg)
{
  return atoi<uint16_t>(arg);
}

template<> inline int32_t lexical_cast<int32_t,char const *>(const char * const & arg)
{
  return atoi<int32_t>(strtol, arg);
}

template<> inline uint32_t lexical_cast<uint32_t,char const *>(const char * const & arg)
{
  return atoi<uint32_t>(strtoul, arg);
}

template<> inline int64_t lexical_cast<int64_t,char const *>(const char * const & arg)
{
  return atoi<int64_t>(_strtoi64, arg);
}

template<> inline uint64_t lexical_cast<uint64_t,char const *>(const char * const & arg)
{
  return atoi<uint64_t>(_strtoui64, arg);
}

template<> inline double lexical_cast<double,char const *>(const char * const & arg)
{
  char* stop;
  double res = strtod(arg, &stop);
  if (*stop)
  {
    throw_exception(bad_lexical_cast(typeid(double), typeid(const char *)));
  }
  return res;
}

template<> inline float lexical_cast<float,char const *>(const char * const & arg)
{
  char* stop;
  double res = strtod(arg, &stop);
  if (*stop || -FLT_MAX > res || FLT_MAX < res)
  {
    throw_exception(bad_lexical_cast(typeid(float), typeid(const char *)));
  }
  return res;
}

}
```

So, in the end I am using the `strtol` family of functions. Unfortunately, the guy who has suggested to use them has also deleted his post, I wonder why...

Comment: There are strol and strtoll, strtoq.

Comment: there are `atoi`, `atol`, `atoll`, and it's enough, because all types you mentioned can be converted to `long long` or `int` without overflow issues

Comment: Those are typedefs. If you specialize or overload on typedefs, you are in for a big surprise!

Comment: @mark, might I ask the actual reason why (besides niceness) you want these functions? The `ato*` family always looked quite broken to me, as they return `0` both for legit `0` and for erroneous input.

Comment: You are right. The error support of `strtol` should be embraced by the `atoi` family of functions.

Comment: Using them requires extra work to make sure the input does not overflow. It is not much of a labor, but still tedious and boring.

Comment: Well, I can you give no better answer to your question where are those functions :)

Comment: @mark - `int32_t` and `int16_t` surely correspond to one of `long`, `int`, or `short`. These already have specializations and overloads for many functions. Adding duplicates for those will violate the One Definition Rule.

Comment: @Bo You would be right if there were specializations for what I am looking for. But I cannot find any in the boost library, this is why I am doing it in the first place. If you know them - please share.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `scanf` family of `<cstdio>` functions implements all the required conversions, and `<cinttypes>` (in C++11; `<inttypes.h>` in a combined C++98 compiler with C99 library) defines the appropriate format string specifiers. E.g., to read in an `int16_t` from the C string `s`, do

```
int16_t i;
std::sscanf(s, "%"SCNd16, &i);
```

Comment: Visual Studio does not support these. There is no cinttypes header in VS2010.

Comment: @mark: neither is `int16_t` required in a pre-C++11 compiler. You can get a replacement `inttypes.h` from various sources, e.g. http://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/.

Comment: Do you want to say that I can just define SCNXXX macros? Are their values recognized by VS2010?

Comment: @mark: they're just macros expanding to the right format string, e.g. `SVNd16` would expand to `"hd"` in VC++ because `int16_t` is a `typedef` for `signed short`.