# C++ read int16_t (G++ compiler)

Tags: c++, stdint

I need store value in **int16_t** from **stdint.h**. How can I read this value from user's terminal?

The way from this answer ([So, we have int32_t, int16_t, uint64_t, etc.. But where are the atoi32, atoi16, atoui64, etc...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977561/so-we-have-int32-t-int16-t-uint64-t-etc-but-where-are-the-atoi32-atoi16)) doesn't work on Ubuntu g++ compiler.

I prefer use standard C++ libraries. Something like:

```
#include <cstdio> 
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ( void ) {
    char value [] = "111";
    int16_t tmp;

    if ( sscanf ( value, "%???", & tmp) == 1 ) cout << "OK" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or is better read standard integer and then convert it?

I don't use C++11.

Comment: Are you using C++11? If that is the case you need to add a space between the string literal and identifier: `scanf( "%" SCNd16, &tmp);` because otherwise it will interpret it as a suffix.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write it. I don't use C++11, but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using old C functions, and start using C++ functionality:

```
std::string value = "111";

std::istringstream is(value);
if (is >> tmp)
    std::cout << "OK\n";
```

If you want to read it from the user, then use `std::cin` instead:

```
if (std::cin >> tmp)
    std::cout << "OK\n";
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks :-). I don't know why I thought that stream don't like the types from stdint.h.

Comment: @PeterK. In most cases on modern computers, `uint16_t` is just an alias for `unsigned short`.

Comment: Does stream io really make c-style printf / scanf semantics obsolete ?
Is std>>cin>>>std::blah::blahblah::yadaddadadada>>some_weird_anaconda_snake_long_expression really that much superior to the good ole sscanf ? I am yet to see a C++ developer who would give me an unqualified "yes" on this one.

Comment: @AlexK It's better because it's completely type safe. With `scanf` and family you can easily provide a pointer to another type than the format. Granted, a good compiler might warn about some cases like this, but with a C++ input stream you get an error about it. I'd say it's better.

Comment: @Joachim I can see how people are willing to trade safety for performance and convenience.

Comment: @AlexK What am I missing, I do not understand why some say the printf an scanf functions are more convenient? Also on performance, I benchmarked it on visual studio streams were slower and on gcc streams were faster (gcc was the faster of the two).